# Remove words from a column in a file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

I have file which contains something like below

```
5,test,2019-09-27T11:06:23Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-27T11:09:28Z,2,2
4,test,2019-09-26T16:56:40Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:57:02Z,1,1
3,test,2019-09-26T16:54:25Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:54:55Z,1,1
2,test,2019-09-26T16:52:59Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:55:19Z,1,1
1,test,2019-09-26T16:46:52Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:47:25Z,1,1
```

I want to trim the 3rd column `2019-09-27T11:06:23Z` to `2019-09-27`
Basically I want to remove time and just keep date here.

```
4,test,2019-09-26,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:57:02Z,1,1
3,test,2019-09-26,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:54:55Z,1,1
2,test,2019-09-26,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:55:19Z,1,1
1,test,2019-09-26,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:47:25Z,1,1
```

I tried using awk with gsub 
`awk '{gsub("T","",$3);print}' test`

But no luck, please help how can I achieve this.

Comment: ```sed -E 's/T([0-9]+:)+[0-9]+Z//g' file```

Comment: @bac0n This try to find all the columns to that particular pattern, I want this to be replaced only in 3rd column.

Comment: just remove 'g'

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ awk -F, '{sub(/T.*/,"",$3);print}' OFS=, file
5,test,2019-09-27,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-27T11:09:28Z,2,2
4,test,2019-09-26,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:57:02Z,1,1
3,test,2019-09-26,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:54:55Z,1,1
2,test,2019-09-26,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:55:19Z,1,1
1,test,2019-09-26,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:47:25Z,1,1
```

Notes:

1. Your file is comma separated.  Thus, you need to specify `-F,` so that, on input, each line is divided into fields based on commas.
2. Since you want a comma-separated file on output, we also need to specify `OFS=,`.
3. The first argument to `sub` (or `gsub`) should be a regular expression not a string.  In our case the regular expression should match `T` and everything after.  `.*` means everything after.
4. Since awk programmers often pride themselves on conciseness, you might want to remove `print` (too long-winded) and instead use:

   ```
   awk -F, '{sub(/T.*/,"",$3)} 1' OFS=, file
   ```